# Code won't work when looping through directory: TypeError: dispatcher for __array_function__ did not return an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a boolean column ('flag_rise') that marks instances where numbers are increasing in a different column ('Zoom')-so marking it as True when a number is larger than the number before it. The code I wrote works when I run it on one file, but when I try to run it through the directory, I get this error: TypeError: dispatcher for **array_function** did not return an iterable. I can't find much about this error online. I've double checked the files by running the code on a subset of files, and I got the same error. The files are all formatted the same way. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
directory = os.chdir(r"directory")

# create list of files
dir_list = os.listdir(directory)

for file in dir_list:
    
    def rise (a):
        return np.concatenate((False),a[1:] > a[:-1])
    df['flag_rise'] = rise(df.Zoom.values)
```

Comment: Running off to the web to find an exact match works with unusual errors that are often the product of some recent version mismatch.  But it shouldn't be your first step.  Show the full traceback.  While you iterate on `dir_list`, the code you show doesn't use `file`.  Have you tested with `concatenate` expression in isolation?

Comment: Once you've identified which expression gives the problem, you should check the docs for the relevant function.  Make sure your arguments match its expectations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concatenate` expects a list of arrays (or at least an `iterable`) as the first argument.  The second is supposed to be an integer, an `axis`.

```
In [421]: np.concatenate((False),np.array([True, False]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-421-2e0a61c32e56>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate((False),np.array([True, False]))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
TypeError: dispatcher for __array_function__ did not return an iterable
```

The first argument is `(False)`.  The () do nothing here, this is just `False`, not a list, tuple or other iterable.  The second argument is a array.

Changing the brackets to wrap both `False` and the array is not enough, because `False` is still a scalar (or 0d array):

```
In [422]: np.concatenate([False,np.array([True, False])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-422-f6c715674042>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate([False,np.array([True, False])])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Make `False` a list, then it works:

```
In [423]: np.concatenate([[False],np.array([True, False])])
Out[423]: array([False,  True, False])
```

`concatenate` converts all those elements of the list to arrays:

```
In [425]: np.array(False)
Out[425]: array(False)
In [426]: _.shape
Out[426]: ()
In [427]: __.ndim
Out[427]: 0
```

It can't join a () shape array to a (2,) shape on axis 0.  The arrays have to match in the number of dimensions.